# changing wpdb object after WP is loaded

Tags: php, wordpress, yii

I'm using Wordpress within Yii. I load wordpress by calling `require_once('wp/wp-load.php');` before `Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();`. All this is working perfectly, loading pages, running queries.etc.

New problem: I have another wordpress blog. and I want to switch my wordpress context from first db to second db. And to do that within a controller-action. I recreated `$wpdb` with new db params. But the wordpress options are still old. How do I tell wordpress to initialise again?

Comment: maybe as simple as `$_GLOBALS['wpdb'] = $newWpdbObject` ?

Comment: options dont change. i suspect they are cached in globals. they are not fetched from db always.